# What is the frequency of Gaussian white noise in a Bode plot?

Tags: frequency, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The design of control systems, particularly for SISO systems, is made convenient by tools such as [Bode plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot) and the corresponding [Nyquist stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_stability_criterion#Nyquist_plot). These concepts allow engineers to design sufficient margins for the given system in a model based paradigm, when it's transfer function is known. Specifically in the Bode plot, the frequencies correspond to sinusoidal input signals and the plot provides information about the gain and phase margin available for stability. The idea is that by knowing the worst case of frequencies one can design the controller to reject disturbances.

However, in the case of stochastic noise, say the commonly used model of Gaussian white noise, it is not clear to me what the corresponding frequency representing this type of noise would be on the Bode plot. I have two questions:

1. What is the frequency of the Gaussian white noise model in control systems? The first variation (time derivative) of this noise is infinite indicating very large frequency.
2. Is there a frequency-domain representation of Gaussian white noise (that is the Laplace transform of the Brownian motion)?

Comment: "White noise" literally means that the spectral density is constant, i.e. does not depend on frequency. Also, asking three questions in one post often prevents anyone from answering, because they need to answer three questions. If you instead ask just one question per post, it's more likely to get a good answer. For example, I can answer two of your questions, but not all three, so I'm prevented from writing an answer.

Comment: @DanielSank I have edited the question to be more focused. Thanks for the comment. It would be good if you can comment on what the Laplace transform of the Brownian motion and how the spectral density relates to the frequency of sinusoidal input signals, such as $sin(\omega t$) with angular frequency $0 < \omega$, used in frequency domain controls analysis.